# Power BI Check If Value Takes Place Before a Certain Time

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I have data that looks like this:

Joined Time null null 10:01:00 AM 02:20:00 AM

I want to add a column that has the following logic:

```
If "Joined Time" < 09:00:00 AM then "PM" 
if "Joined Time >= 09:00:00 AM AND "Joined Time" < 12:00:00 PM then "AM" 
else null
```

Any suggestions on how to implement this? I am newish with doing complex stuff in PowerBI.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices for logic like this - Power Query (Add Column ribbon in Power Query Editor) or DAX (Add Column button or right-click option in main Power BI window).  They have completely separate syntax.

Generally I prefer Power Query, but for time logic DAX is easier. The syntax is based on Excel formulas. The trickiest part is how to enter your constant values e.g. 09:00:00 AM. For that you can use the DAX TIME function.

Here's how it might look:

```
AM PM = IF ( [Joined Time] < TIME ( 9, 00, 00 ), "PM" ,
IF ( [Joined Time] >= TIME ( 9, 00, 00 ) && [Joined Time] < TIME ( 12, 00, 00 ) , "AM" ) )
```